# how can I use apply on two variables simultaneously

Tags: r

suppose I have

```
# test case
a<-matrix(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),3),ncol=3)
b<-t(matrix(c(1,3,4)))

a

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4
[5,]    5    5    5
[6,]    6    6    6

b

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    4
```

Each element of `b` "corresponds" to a column of `a` and needed in a function as follows:

I have a function `myFun`

```
myfun<-function(x,n) {
   x[1:n]<-NA
   x
}
```

and I want to use it to return

```
t<-cbind(myfun(a[,1],b[1]), myfun(a[,2],b[2]), myfun(a[,3],b[3]))

t
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    2   NA   NA
[3,]    3   NA   NA
[4,]    4    4   NA
[5,]    5    5    5
[6,]    6    6    6
```

How can I achieve the above using `apply` / `lapply` / `sapply` without using a `for` loop?

For instance, I try `apply(a,2,FUN=myfun,b)`, then the whole `b` is passed to `myfun` instead of `b[1]` or `b[2]` etc.

How can I rewrite `apply(a,2,FUN=myfun,b)` such that `myfun` will only pick up that element of `b` corresponding to the respective column of `a`?

Comment: Try `mapply` or `Map`

Comment: Thanks, `mapply` solves my problem and is what I was looking for. If can rewrite your comment as an answer, I can select it as an answer in SO.

Comment: That's fine. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use vector subsetting for this task:

```
(NAcells <- unlist(sapply(seq_along(b), function(i) seq(b[i])+(i-1)*nrow(a))))
[1]  1  7  8  9 13 14 15 16

a[NAcells] <- NA
a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    2   NA   NA
[3,]    3   NA   NA
[4,]    4    4   NA
[5,]    5    5    5
[6,]    6    6    6
```

Comment: The only place it breaks down is if any element of `b` is zero.